# Transfer Information into constructor

Tags: java

i've stuck on transfering information i've got into constructor. How to do it correctly? :)

I've tried to look into some docs, but haven't find anything :( 
Also, how to put those "f's " from my If's out ?

(From position to binarySearch)

```
public class BinarySearchRecursive {
public static void main(String[] args) {



        System.out.print("Bitte wählen Sie die Folge von 1 bis 5 aus: ");
        Scanner eingabe = new Scanner(System.in);
        int folge = eingabe.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Bitte geben Sie den Suchschlüssel ein:  " );
        Scanner eingabe1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        int key = eingabe1.nextInt();

        int [] f;



       if (folge == 1){
           f= new int[]{20};

           }
       if (folge==2){
          f= new int []{3,4};

           }
       if (folge==3){
           f= new int []{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11};
           }
       if (folge==4){
           f= new int []{10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110};
           }
       if (folge==5){
           f= new int [] {20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40};
            }

       int position = binarySearch (f, key, 0, f.length -1);
       }


       public static int binarySearch (int [] f, int key, int intervallgrenzeLinks, int intervallgrenzeRechts){


           int NO_KEY = -2;
           if (intervallgrenzeLinks <= intervallgrenzeRechts){
               int m = (intervallgrenzeLinks + intervallgrenzeRechts)/ 2;

               if ( key == f[m]) {
                   return m;
                   } else if ( key < f[m]){
                       intervallgrenzeRechts = m-1;
                   }else {
                       intervallgrenzeLinks = m+1;
                   }


           } else {
               return NO_KEY;
           }
           return binarySearch (f, key, intervallgrenzeLinks, intervallgrenzeRechts );



       }



    }
```

Comment: what exactly is the problem? you can't take out the "f=.." from your "if"s

Comment: What class are you trying to construct?

Comment: Instead of `if (folge == 1){...} if(folge == 2) {...} etc.`  you could use a switch-statement: `switch(folge){ case 1: ... break; case 2: ... break; }` or use some map-based approach (though that's probably out of scope for now).

Comment: I'll try switch case when this will finally work, thank you :) Well, the problem is at "int position = binarySearch (f, key, 0, f.length -1);"   . He don't get the "f" value from If's. So the binarySearch don't work properply =(

Comment: I think you mean method/function instead of constructor right?

Comment: Oh..I think i've mixed them both. Sorry ^^ The point is,  1) I can't get the values of my f arry to my "int position = binarySearch (f, key, 0, f.length -1);". Elcipse is forcing me to declare int [] f = null;  Also, because of this, i can't run my next Method properly :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for your problem either replace`int[] f;` with `int[] f = new int[0];`
or add an else like this:

```
else{
    f=new int[0];
}
```

now it should work as wanted. and to actually get an output do this `System.out.println(binarySearch(f, key, 0, f.length - 1));`

Comment: Yay, it's worked! Can u explain why it doesn't work with int position = binarySearch (f, key, 0, f.length -1); ?  At the documentation, they've transfered on such way the values :)

Comment: your code works as well but you never printed it. also you have to initialize every variable you want to use. if you initialize only in ifs there is the possibility that the variable does not get initialized. therefore either add else or initialize it with a starting value and then overwrite it